# Preloading a youtube embed

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube, embedding

I want to have an embedded chromeless youtube video preload its video WITHOUT playing when the page loads. Right now I'm using an awkward "play then quickly pause" script which causes small problems (half-second audio leaks and fails quite a bit). For this seemingly simple functionality, is there a better/more elegant way to preload?

Comment: Nowadays you could use [plyr](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr) with [dash.js to preload it](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/blob/development/samples/getting-started-basic-embed/pre-load-video.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same question and came across this question. After some research, I think I found a cleaner, albeit similar, answer.

When the JavaScript API calls `OnYouTubePlayerReady`, you press play and add an event listener to `onStateChange` that will be called every time the player changes from buffering to play.

For example, inside the function you listen for state 3, which is buffering, and as soon as it's called, you pause the video.

You can see this technique in action in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TxaHE/1/).

Side note: I refrained from using a JavaScript framework in my example, but you could easily put one into place here.

Also, I was unable to abstract the script tag out of the body of the HTML using jsFiddle, but an external `script.js` file works just fine on my own server.

Comment: I found that state 3 wasn't always part of the loading sequence on my high speed connection. Instead what worked was listening to the play state, muting the audio, and pausing.

Comment: As of 2017.11.12, when I try to run the JSFiddle in Chrome I see `You need Flash Player version 8 or higher to view this content.`

Answer (score 0):

If we view this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content

Preloading the Iframe may help:

```
    <link rel="preload" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" as="document">
```

Answer (score -1):

Call

```
player.cueVideoById(videoId:String);
```

Instead of

```
player.loadVideoById(videoId:String);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. From the official docs: "cueVideoByID: Loads the specified video's thumbnail and prepares the player to play the video. The player does not request the FLV until playVideo() or seekTo() is called." In other words, it doesn't actually start buffering the clip.

Comment: You are right. It seems like the only way would be to do it the way you are doing it. I can suggest trying to listen for the event "playerStateChanged" and seeing if the state is playing (1) then call pause. You might be able to pause it sooner.

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for a solution to this problem and ran across this article:

[Embed YouTube Videos Responsively without Increasing Load Time](http://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/)

The summary states: This method will reduce the size of your webpages by 300-400 KB while making your site mobile friendly.

**Paste this on the page**:

```
<div class="youtube-container">
<div class="youtube-player" data-id="VIDEOID"></div>
</div>
```

**The javascript**:

```
<script>
(function() {
    var v = document.getElementsByClassName("youtube-player");
    for (var n = 0; n < v.length; n++) {
        var p = document.createElement("div");
        p.innerHTML = labnolThumb(v[n].dataset.id);
        p.onclick = labnolIframe;
        v[n].appendChild(p);
    }
})();

function labnolThumb(id) {
    return '<img class="youtube-thumb" src="//i.ytimg.com/vi/' + id + '/hqdefault.jpg"><div class="play-button"></div>';
}

function labnolIframe() {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("src", "//www.youtube.com/embed/" +
        this.parentNode.dataset.id + "?  autoplay=1&autohide=2&border=0&wmode=opaque&enablejsapi=1&controls=0&showinfo=0");
    iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("id", "youtube-iframe");
    this.parentNode.replaceChild(iframe, this);
}
</script>
```

**The CSS**:

```
<style>
.youtube-container {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
}
.youtube-player {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    /* assuming that the video has a 16:9 ratio */

    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}
img.youtube-thumb {
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: auto
}
div.play-button {
    height: 72px;
    width: 72px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -36px;
    margin-top: -36px;
    position: absolute;
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/TxzC70f.png") no-repeat;
}
#youtube-iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
</style>
```

Refer to the original article comments for additional modification suggestions and improvements.

Comment: I could be missing something, but from having read the article, this code doesn't preload a YouTube video without playing it, and thus is not an answer to the question as stated.